# Get current edited text from tag with attribute contenteditable='true'

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am working on an XML editor in ASP.Net that allows the user to open an XML file, then edit and save that XML file. Everything works except for when the user attempts to save the file it saves it from the context it was loaded in, rather than the newly edited version.

The FileUpload control only works in IE right now, but I plan on passing the directory from other web apps after this is fully functional, so there will be no need for it later.

CSS:

```
#lineNum
{
min-width:30px;
float:left;
color:#F8F8F2;
border-right:1px solid #F8F8F2;
margin-right:10px;
/*
UNSELECTABLE
*/
-moz-user-select: -moz-none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
#editor
{
width:100%;
}
.tagName
{
color:#f92772;
}
.tagVal
{
color:#fd9620;
}
.attrName
{
color:#bce9fd;
}
.attrVal
{
color:#bc95ff;
}
.comment
{
color:#75715e !important;   
}
body
{
background-color:#272822;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Menlo;
color: orange;
}
a
{
color:#bce9fd;   
}
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace XML
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static bool comment;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void menu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
        {
            fileUp.Visible = false;
            switch (e.Item.Text)
            {
                case "Open":
                    fileUp.Visible = true;
                    break;
                case "Save":
                    saveXml(fileContents.Text);
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected void openFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (getFile.HasFile)
            {
                lblFileLoc.Text = getFile.PostedFile.FileName;
                /*lblFileLoc.Text = Server.MapPath(@".\tmp\temp.xml");
                getFile.SaveAs(lblFileLoc.Text);*/
                lblFileName.Text = getFile.FileName;
                lblStat.Text = "Current File: <a href='" + lblFileLoc.Text + "'>" + lblFileName.Text + "</a>";
                fileUp.Visible = false;
                fileContents.Text = "<pre contenteditable='true'>";
                lineNum.InnerText = "\n\n";
                string[] xml = File.ReadAllLines(lblFileLoc.Text);
                comment = false;
                for (int i = 1; i <= xml.Length; i++)
                {
                    lineNum.InnerText += i + "\n";
                    fileContents.Text += highlightLine(xml[i - 1]);
                }
                fileContents.Text += "</pre>";
            }
        }

        public void saveXml(string xml)
        {
            xml = xml.Replace("<XMP class='comment'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("<XMP class='attrName'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("<XMP class='attrVal'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("<XMP class='tagName'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("<XMP class='tagVal'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("</XMP>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("<pre contenteditable='true'>", "");
            xml = xml.Replace("</pre>", "");
            if (xml.Trim().Length > 0)
                File.WriteAllText(lblFileLoc.Text, xml);
        }

        protected string highlightLine(string line)
        {
            string hlString = "";
            int lastIndex = 0;
            while (line.IndexOf('<', lastIndex) > -1)
            {
                int openStart = (line.Contains("<!--")) ? line.IndexOf("<!--", lastIndex) : line.IndexOf('<', lastIndex);
                int openEnd = (line.Contains("-->")) ? line.IndexOf("-->", openStart) : line.IndexOf('>', openStart);
                hlString += line.Substring(0, openStart);

                if (line.Contains("<!--") || line.Contains("-->"))
                {
                    if (line.Contains("<!--") && line.Contains("-->"))
                        hlString += "<XMP class='comment'>" + line.Substring(openStart, (openEnd + 3 - openStart));
                    if (line.Contains("<!--") && !line.Contains("-->"))
                    {
                        comment = true;
                        hlString += "<XMP class='comment'>" + line.Substring(openStart, (line.Length - openStart));
                        break;
                    } 
                    if (!line.Contains("<!--") && line.Contains("-->"))
                        hlString += line.Substring(openStart, (line.Length - openStart));
                    if (line.Contains("-->"))
                    {
                        hlString += "</XMP>";
                        comment = false;
                        if (line.Substring((line.Length-3), 3) == "-->")
                            break;
                        else
                            lastIndex = openEnd;
                    }
                }
                else if (comment)
                {
                    hlString += line.Substring(openStart, (line.Length - openStart));
                    lastIndex = openEnd;
                }
                if (!comment)
                {
                    if (line.IndexOf('=', lastIndex) > -1)
                    {
                        string[] words = line.Substring(openStart, (openEnd + 1 - openStart)).Split(' ');
                        foreach (string word in words)
                        {
                            if (word.Contains('='))
                            {
                                string[] attr = word.Split('=');
                                hlString += "<XMP class='attrName'>" + attr[0] + "</XMP>=<XMP class='attrVal'>";

                                if (attr[1].Contains("/>"))
                                    hlString += attr[1].Replace("/>", "") + "</XMP><XMP class='tagName'>/></XMP>";
                                else if (attr[1].Contains(">"))
                                    hlString += attr[1].Replace(">", "") + "</XMP><XMP class='tagName'>></XMP>";
                                else if (attr[1].Contains("?>"))
                                    hlString += attr[1].Replace("?>", "") + "</XMP><XMP class='tagName'>?></XMP>";
                                else
                                    hlString += attr[1] + "</XMP> ";
                            }
                            else
                                hlString += "<XMP class='tagName'>" + word + "</XMP> ";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        hlString += "<XMP class='tagName'>" + line.Substring(openStart, (openEnd + 1 - openStart)) + "</XMP>";
                    }
                    lastIndex = openEnd;
                    if (!line.Substring(openStart, (lastIndex + 1 - openStart)).Contains('/') && line.IndexOf('<', lastIndex) > -1)
                    {
                        int closeStart = line.IndexOf('<', lastIndex);
                        int closeEnd = line.IndexOf('>', lastIndex + 1);
                        if (line.Substring(closeStart, (closeEnd + 1 - closeStart)).Contains('/'))
                        {
                            hlString += "<XMP class='tagVal'>" + line.Substring((lastIndex + 1), (closeStart - lastIndex - 1)) + "</XMP>";
                            hlString += "<XMP class='tagName'>" + line.Substring(closeStart, (closeEnd + 1 - closeStart)) + "</XMP>";
                            lastIndex = closeEnd;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return hlString + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

ASP:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="index.aspx.cs" Inherits="XML.index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Menu ID="menu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                onmenuitemclick="menu_MenuItemClick"  BackColor="#272822" ForeColor="orange">
                <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor="#272822" ForeColor="orange" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="File">
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Open" Value="Open"></asp:MenuItem>
                        <asp:MenuItem Text="Save" Value="Save"></asp:MenuItem>
                    </asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
            <asp:Label ID="lblStat" runat="server" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblFileName" runat="server" Visible="False"  />
            <asp:Label ID="lblFileLoc" runat="server" Visible="False" />
            <br />
            <div id="fileUp" runat="server" visible="False">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="getFile" runat="server"></asp:FileUpload>
                <asp:Button ID="openFile" Text="Open" runat="server" onclick="openFile_Click"/>
            </div>
            <div id="editor">
                <pre id="lineNum" runat="server"></pre>
                <pre>
                    <asp:Literal ID="fileContents" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe your problem with saving is file permission.

Comment: What link are you trying to paste? I can edit your post and paste it for you.

Comment: @Dozer789 the link was for the [CSS](http://pastebin.com/RfURVGWD)

Comment: @SeyedMortezaMousavi The file saves fine. But it saves the file the way it was originally rendered, without any of the changes.

Comment: I just added the CSS Link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using JS.

I got the value of 'fileContents' and placed it into a hidden field called 'rawXML':

```
document.getElementById("rawXML").value = document.getElementById("fileContents").innerText;
```

then I used the value of the 'rawXML' and wrote that to the file. It's a pretty choppy workaround though, let me know if anyone finds a better way.